# How to Monitor for Input Device Addition and Removal with a Linux Netlink Socket

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, udev, netlink

I want to be able to monitor for device removal and addition of input devices using linux netlink sockets. Scouring the web, I have found source code that reads a netlink socket message but does no parsing on its type or content and just prints a *"message recieved"* string.

If I have `int fd = open("/dev/input/event0", O_RDONLY)`, how do I:

1. Determine that the received `uevent` is related to this device. Or in case of a new addition, what the new device's path is.
2. Determine that the type of the received `uevent` is indicating either an addition or deletion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48766482/how-to-capture-kobject-uevent-using-c-program and https://stackoverflow.com/a/40806887/10334333

Comment: @Vencat thank you for those links. The first one in particular. I knew I had seen it previously but could not find it again.